# Parse local datastore relation

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I've a class called category, and I have retrieved my categories from local datastore through query.getFromLocalDataStore().

Next I've the following code

```
var userExpense = PFObject(className: "Expenses")
userExpense["category"] = category 
userExpense.saveEventually()
userExpense.pin()
```

And now i'm getting this error,

```
{error={"__type":"Pointer","className":"Category","localId":"local_55876b12913120b9"} is not a valid Pointer, code=106}
```

Any idea why? I wanted

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you downloaded the *category* variable as a PFObject, not as a pointer. What you can do, is to create a pointer from your *category* with the method:

```
objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:
```

and set that to *userExpense["category"]*, and that will be a valid pointer.